# Why is this variable inside of a for loop not being reset to it's initial value?

Tags: java, for-loop, variables, while-loop, variable-assignment

I have this programme code which tries to create something similar to a monte carlo simulation. Essentially the gambler starts with given £ stake and places £1 fair bets until going broke or reaching a goal.

The programme code works as expected however, the problem I have is with the statement "int cash = stake;" I would like to know how the variable "cash" is updated correctly with each iteration.

I am confused as to why it isn't reset back to the initial value of "stake" which is a user input outside of the main for loop. For example, if the goal is 500 and the stake is 100, why doesn't cash always remain 100 and if it does, how will it reach the goal of 500?

```
public static void monteCarlo() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter stake, goal, " + " and number of tries");
    int stake = input.nextInt();
    int goal = input.nextInt();
    int tries = input.nextInt();
    int wins = 0;
    // repeat experiment
    for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
        // do one gambler's ruin experiment
        int cash = stake;
        while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
            // flip coin and update
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) cash++;
            else cash--;
        }

        if (cash >= goal) {
            wins++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(wins + " wins of " + tries);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: `cash` is reset in the for-loop and incremented or decremented in the while-loop. What don't you understand?

Comment: @Michael Yes but if cash is reset in the for loop, then it will never reach it's goal. Lets say, Cash is 100 to begin with and the goal is 500. How will it reach this goal if it is reset back to 100 on every iteration of the for loop?

Comment: @RayZe, `cash` is modified inside a while loop, and the player either reaches their goal or busts inside that while loop.  Then, _after_ the player either wins or loses, the for loop hits the next iteration and resets `cash`.

Comment: The for-loop represents N "games". In each of the N games, the cash starts at `stake`, then either (in the while-loop) gets incremented or decremented until there is none remaining, or they reached their goal. Then the next game starts (next iteration of the for-loop) and the cash is reset.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Math.random() < 0.5) cash++;
```

There's a 50% chance of `cash` being incremented here. On average the value of `cash` stays pretty much the same.

To get `cash` from 100 to 500, you'll need around `400` wins in a game with 50% win probability.

Keep running the program and you might get lucky :)

Answer (score 0):

The line `int cash = stake` **does** (re)set the cash variable to always-the-same initial value !

If you input 5 trials and a stake of 12, then

1. cash is reset to 12.
2. the while-loop does increment/decrement cash at each trial
3. until the goal is reached or there is no more cash

Steps from 1. to 3. will be called again 5 times. Each of the 5 times it will start from 12 but the `cash++` and `cash--`instructions will change it until it reaches a final condition.

Running the verbose variant below may help you get it more clearly...

```java
package so20190412;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        System.out.println("Please enter stake, goal, " + " and number of tries");
        int stake = input.nextInt();
        int goal = input.nextInt();
        int tries = input.nextInt();

        monteCarlo(stake, goal, tries);

        }
    }



    public static void monteCarlo(final int stake, final int goal, final int tries) {

        System.out.println("Starting with a stake of " + stake);
        System.out.println("Goal is " + goal);
        System.out.println("Will try : " + tries + " times");

        int wins = 0;
        // repeat experiment
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
            // do one gambler's ruin experiment

            System.out.println("### ITERATION " + (i+1));
            int cash = stake;

            System.out.println(cash);
            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
                // flip coin and update
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    cash++;
                    System.out.println("WIN! get one more € - new cash is " + cash);
                }
                else {
                    cash--;
                System.out.println("LOST one € - new cash is " + cash);
            }
            }

            if (cash >= goal) {
                wins++;
                System.out.println("Cash is over goal - add a win!");
            }
            System.out.println("END OF ITERATION - stake : " + stake + " cash:" + cash + " wins:" + wins);
        }

        System.out.println(wins + " wins of " + tries);
    }

}
```

Hope this clarifies the situation !